# How to compare members in a list of records in erlang

Tags: erlang

`Sched_ents` is a list of records of type `l1_dl_se` which has `dci` as one of its element/field name, which itself is a record of different types, one of its types is `l1_format0`. I am trying to see if there is any `dci` record of type `l1_format0` in any of the records in the list `Sched_ents`. If there is such a member in any of the record in the list, return `x=1` otherwise `x=2`.

I tried using lists:keymember as:

```
case lists:keymember(l1_format0,#l1_dl_se.dci,Sched_ents) of
                         true  -> X=1;
                         false -> X=2
end
```

Comment: The question is unclear - could you provide some sample values for the variables/records here please?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Please review the question. I have made some changes.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still unclear on what you are trying to do here. Is `sched_ents` a variable?

Comment: Perhaps you mean something like: `[ X || X <- Sched_ents, X#l1_dl_se.dci =:= l1_format0 ]` which will return only the elements in Sched_ents which have the `dci` field with value `'l1_format0'`. If `#l1_dl_se.dci` is an actual record (not the name of a record) then you can use `is_record(X#l1_dl_se.dci, l1_format0)`

Comment: thanks again..."dci" is one one of the field name in a record of type l1_dl_se. dci itself is also record. sched_ents is a list of records of type l1_dl_se. I want to see if there is dci record of type l1_format0 in any of the records in the list sched_ents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, I think you're looking for something like this:

```
case [ X || X <- Sched_ents,
      is_record(X, l1_dl_se),
      is_record(X#l1_dl_se.dci, l1_format0)] of
    [] -> 2; %% none found
    _List -> 1 %% One or more found
end
```

The list comprehension gives you a list of strictly only those elements in `Sched_ents` which are a `#l1_dl_se` record, and which contain a `#l1_format0` record.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `lists:any/2` which make short circuit evaluation:

```
F = fun(#l1_dl_se{dci = #l1_format0{}}) -> true; (_) -> false end,
case lists:any(F, Sched_ents) of
    true  -> X = 1;
    false -> X = 1
end
```

Using `erlang:is_record/2` will work as well

```
F = fun(X) -> is_record(X, l1_dl_se) andalso is_record(X#l1_dl_se.dci, l1_format0) end,
```